# SQL query generation - Cosmos DB

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application where am making use of dbcontext to do few DB operations. My database is Azure Cosmos DB, I want to see the underlying final query that gets executed in cosmos DB in my code while debugging.

My code looks like this:

```cs
var item = _dbContext.Set<SampleDoc>().Where(et => et.caseId == caseId);
var sqlQuery = item.ToQueryString();
```

In the sqlQuery variable I see that only partial query gets stored and I don't see the "WHERE" condition at all in the query generated, I want to know the reason behind this.

Comment: No reason, looks like a bug.

Comment: But in the end when I see the final records I observe that the filtration has happened based on where condition , it's just that I cannot see it in the query.

Comment: Can you show what `sqlQuery` actually is?

Comment: @Aishwarya.R, I mean bug in functionality for `ToQueryString()`

Comment: @LajosArpad - It just looks like this without a where clause => SELECT c
FROM root c
WHERE (c["documentType"] = "SampleDoc")

Comment: Does the query work? CosmosDB isn't a relational database. It *does* have a SQL facade and API, but the *quickest* way to get a document by its ID or specific attributes is to make a REST call with the proper arguments.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv CosmosDB isn't an RDBMS and the provider may be using the REST API instead of SQL. After all, ORMs exist to give the impression of working as if you had an object database. No need to generate SQL if you *do* have an object API

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `ToQueryString()` method it doesn't work for me. It shows like below:

> To execute LINQ query please set allowSynchronousQueryExecution true or use GetItemQueryIterator to execute asynchronously

As per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-7.0), `ToQueryString()` is used for generating logging and debugging information, not for executing database queries.

- I tried using `ToString()` method, it generates a query that can be executed against my database.
  **Code I tried with:**

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string endpointUri = "*****";
    string primaryKey = "*****";
    string databaseId = "NewDb";
    string containerId = "NewCont";

    CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUri, primaryKey);
    var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

    string entityId = "1"; 

    var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyEntity>()
        .Where(entity => entity.id == entityId);
    var sqlQuery = query.ToString();

    var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator();

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (var entity in response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Entity Id: {entity.id}, Name: {entity.Name}, Age: {entity.Age}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Entity Id: 1, Name: Balaji, Age: 24
```

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to retrieve documents from CosmosDB nor does it say that the document can't be retrieved. It asks *specifically* about using EF Core's `ToQueryString` to see the *request*, not the result

Comment: As mentioned in question "want to see the underlying final query that gets executed in cosmos DB in my code while debugging".  By using **`ToQueryString`** method it shows an error when we debug the code. When `ToString()` method is used we can see the output while debugging.

Comment: And what is that output? This answer shows the query results, not the output of `query.ToString()`. I suspect that output is a type name, not the query